# Parse HTTP JSON Response - C#

Tags: c#, json, http, oauth-2.0

I am working on an OAUTH2 login for a winforms applications.

I have to make a request to our with some credentials, and the server will respond with a token and json format.

What's the best approach to parse out the token value?

Here is the response format:

```
{
    "access_token":"asdfasdfasdfafbasegfnadfgasdfasdfasdf",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a class with those properties and use JSON.NET `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method.

```
public class MyResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
}

MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
// Fill in properties
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Comment: You should deserialize, not serialize. A response is deserialized...

Comment: Thought he want to build a response...in that case if you have the JSON response, then replace `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(jsonString)`.

Comment: @Mark...can you confirm...do you want to extract the `access_token` from a JSON response string?

Answer (score 2):

For less code you could also use JSON.NET with the dynamic type like the following;

```
public void JValueParsingTest()
{
    var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Rick"",""Company"":""West Wind"",
                        ""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

    dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

    // values require casting
    string name = json.Name;
    string company = json.Company;
    DateTime entered = json.Entered;

    Assert.AreEqual(name, "Rick");
    Assert.AreEqual(company, "West Wind");            
}
```

Source:http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing

Comment: I would never use `dynamic` if I don't have to. You don't want compiler errors on runtime.

Comment: I suppose it depends if he is adequately unit testing his work. There is no such thing as compiler errors at run-time, but i know you mean; you would like to benefit from compile time checking. Fair enough. I would recommend staying away from any interpreted languages!

Comment: I wanted to use the "dynamic" method, but part of my C# code is in a Xamarin environment on iOS. Apple doesn't allow dynamically generated code on iOS, so "dynamic" didn't work. Ended up creating the class and using JsonConvert to serialize/deserialize the oauth info as described by @MotoSV. Worked great. However, just to add a little more about how useful "dynamic" has been.... I have some server side code that I use to work with arbitrary JSON data coming in and a Mongo DB. We use "dynamic" all over the place there.